# Expected intersection between a random set and a collection of random sets

Tags: probability

I suspect this question has been posted but I'm unable to find it because I'm not a stats person and might not be using the right terms to search.

A is a set of X random numbers.  I have Y other sets of random numbers that are the same size as A.  I will create a union, Z, from N members of Y and then measure the intersection between A and Z.

I'd like a formula that expresses the expected intersection of A and Z as a percentage of A.

Comment: You'll need to specify how large the sets are, how large the population from which the elements are drawn is, and how the elements of the sets are selected.  For example, if the underlying population is the set of reals, the size of $A$ etc. is $5$, and elements are selected by independent sampling from a Normal distribution, you'll never get coverage of $A$ (with probability $1$) no matter how many other sets you draw.

Comment: Wouldn't the size of A and the size of the population from which its entries are drawn be part of the equation?  In practice, A is ~20,000 entries drawn from a population of 2 x 10^8.

Comment: Ah, for some reason (not enough coffee, perhaps) I thought you were asking for a numerical result, not a formula.  My bad.

Comment: And every set in Y is also ~20,000 entries randomly drawn from the population of 2 x 10^8.

Comment: I can get the results empirically from some scripts but I'd like to include a clean formula just to be succinct.

Comment: Are you selecting the sets by sampling from the population with replacement or without replacement?

Comment: Did you mean to write "union" instead of "intersection" in this question?

Comment: jbowman:  Without replacement.  The population is drawn from the keys of a dictionary.

Comment: @whuber - I interpreted "How many sets in Y do I need to merge..." as "union" and "the intersection of the merged set..." as being the intersection of the union of sets with A, although the OP did leave out the "with A" part.

Comment: jhuber:  I had to google to make sure I have my terms correct and I think intersection is correct.  The sets in Y will form the union, Z.  I'd like to create a formula that will express the expected (size of the intersection of A and Z divided by the size of A) taking A and Y as arguments.

Comment: The problem is that "merge" has no definite meaning and the reference only to "intersection" is highly ambiguous.  "Intersection with $A$" is implied by the word "covers," so the presence of "intersection" where a union is intended seems likely to confuse or mislead readers.  Consider clarifying your post.  cc@jbowman

Comment: whuber:  Thanks for the feedback.  I edited the post and hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

**There are multiple formulas, depending on how the random numbers are selected, but they all have much in common.**

In any case, we can describe all samples by means of suitable collections of random variables.  Index the elements of the population with the integers $j = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ in such a way that $A$ consists of those with indexes $1$ through $m.$  Let $\mathcal Y$ be a collection of $s$ additional samples of size $m,$ written

$$\mathcal Y = \{Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_s\}.$$

For $1 \le i \le s$ and $1 \le j \le n,$ define the random variable $X_{ij}$ to equal $1$ when $j$ is in $Y_{ij}.$ Using the notation of *indicator functions* $\mathcal I,$ this is

$$X_{ij} = \mathcal{I}(j\in Y_i).$$

Consider an element $j\in A.$  It is *not* in the union $\bigcup \mathcal Y$ if and only if $$X_j = \max_{1\le i \le s} X_{ij} = 0;$$ that is, $X_{ij}=0$ for all $i.$

At this point we need to consider how the samples were obtained.  Let $\pi_{ij}$ be the probability that $j \notin Y_i.$  Assuming the samples in $\mathcal Y$ were taken independently of each other means these probabilities multiply:

$$\Pr(X_{1j}=X_{2j}=\cdots=X_{sj}=0) = \pi_{1j}\pi_{2j}\cdots\pi_{sj} = \prod_{i=1}^s \pi_{ij} = \pi_j.$$

(The last equation defines $\pi_j.$)

Thus,

$$\Pr(j \in \bigcup \mathcal Y) = 1 - \pi_j,$$

whence

$$E(X_{j}) = \Pr(j \notin \bigcup \mathcal Y)\times 0 + \Pr(j \in \bigcup \mathcal Y)\times 1 =  1 - \pi_j.$$

The number of elements in $\bigcup \mathcal Y$ common to $A$ is just the sum of the $X_j$ for $j=1,2,\ldots, m,$ whence the expectation of this number is

$$E\left(\left| A \cap \bigcup \mathcal Y \right|\right) = \sum_{j=1}^m E(X_j) = \sum_{j=1}^m 1 - \pi_j.$$

Let's now make some more restrictive assumptions: *assume all $Y_i$ were obtained in a similar fashion and that all elements of the population have equal chances $p$ of being included.*  This implies all the $\pi_i$ are equal to a common value $(1-p)^s.$  The foregoing simplifies to

$$\sum_{j=1}^m 1 - \pi_j = m(1-(1-p)^s).$$

**Dividing by $m = \left| A \right|$ gives the answer as**

$$\frac{E\left(\left| A \cap \bigcup \mathcal Y \right|\right)}{\left| A \right|} = 1-(1-p)^s.$$

I'll give two explicit values to cover standard sampling schemes.

- For sampling with replacement, $p = m/n.$
- For sampling without replacement, $p = 1-\left(1 - 1/n)\right)^m \approx 1-e^{-m/n}.$

The last approximation is excellent when $sm \ll n.$